# Java math with two consecutive operators

Tags: java, android, operators

I was recently debugging a problem where a result was much larger than expected.  What I had intended to write was:

```
y += height + rowHeight * 2;
```

What I had written was

```
y += height * + rowHeight * 2;
```

I didn't see the error right away because, apparently `* +` is a valid operator in Java, or at least Android java.  I've never heard anything about this before, and I have no idea what it means.

As an experiment, I found that the generalized form of this is, as a regex `[*/%][+-]*`

It looks like some form of polish notation, but I was unaware that Java supported such.

So... where would I find documentation about this operator, and what, exactly, does it mean?

Comment: You're just forcing `rowHeight` to be positive.  `*+` isn't an operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's using the *unary plus operator* - so it's like this:

```
y += height * (+rowHeight) * 2;
```

To give an example which wouldn't look odd at all, but using unary *minus* instead of unary plus:

```
y += height * -rowHeight * 2;
```

Hopefully that makes more sense :)

Comment: That _totally_ makes sense now!

Answer (score 0):

`+` is just a positive sign here (a unary operator). You can re-write it like:

```
y += height * (+ rowHeight) * 2;
```

It is also valid to write this in java:

```
int x = +-+-+-+- 5;
```

Comment: What does that result in? `-5` or `5`? Or, is that now a syntax error?

Answer (score 0):

Both `+` and `-` are unary operators as well, otherwise you couldn't write things like:

```
int n = -1;
int x = +42;
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is treating the expression as operator as 
`y += height * (+ rowHeight) * 2;`